# Save data in two table at the same time C# MVC 3 linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

Im using MVC 3 and linq
I have a problem to save data in two table at the same time.
I have a form that include the text input for other column.
so i have 2 table.
table A and table B

in table A: I want to save all data like (ID,NAME,ADD,EMAIL)
in table B : I want to save in one column only like(COMMENT)

here my code for save function:

```
  A.Name = A.Name;
  A.ADD = A.ADD;
  A.EMAIL = A.EMAIL;
  B.Comment = Comment;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
         db.Entry(A).State = EntityState.Modified;
         db.Entry(B).State = EntityState.Modified;
         db.SaveChanges();
         return Content("");
     }
```

so what should i do with the second table ?

Comment: You shouldn't be treating EF like a collection of tables. You should attach to your primary entity and then use navigation properties to join other entities. I'd suggest following some MVC and EF tutorials in the first instance. To help further with this problem, you'll need to post your models for A and B showing the relationships.

Comment: It’s normally not necessarily to use `Stare` unless you are using disconnected contexts which I doubt.

Comment: ok thank you i will try it.